# Android Studio Themes Don't Work in App

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme

I'm just getting started with Android development and have literally only been doing it for a few hours.

Using the new Android Studio I've created a basic one-button app which creates a Toast text when I press it.  Whoopee.

Problem is - when I select a "Theme" for my app layout page from the GUI, and select for example Halo (or any of them), it only changes my PREVIEW in the Android Studio. When I press "Run" (or export it to an apk), everything goes back to basic white style.

It's as if it doesn't include the style/theme when building my app

Answer (score 2):

You may look at this link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

and add something like this

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/NameOftheTheme">
```

or this

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
```

with the theme name you'd like in your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

Thank you! I changed the style.xml file to be this and it changed instantly...

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your activity file extends AppCompatActivity

```
public class ActivityName extends AppCompatActivity {
---------
--------
}
```